# Mysql error in closing the connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have this class for DB interactions. It works fine.

```
<?php require_once('inc/config.inc.php'); ?>
<?php
final class MySQL {
private $link;

public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if (!$this->link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
        //error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);

    }
    if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {
        //error('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
    }
    //echo "open". time();
}

public function __destruct() {
    mysql_close(); // Problem In here
    //echo "closed". time();
}
}

$database=new MySQL(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
?>
```

But if I replace 
    mysql_close(); 
with 
    mysql_close($this->link);

I get an error:
 Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Comment: What happens if you change it from the destructor to your own function, say `close()` and then call that on the `$database` object

Comment: Nothing changes...I still get the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is quite simple: $this->link is a resource. And (quoting [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct) itself)...

> ... a resource with no more references to it is detected automatically,
>   and it is freed by the garbage collector. For this reason, it is
>   rarely necessary to free the memory manually.

In other words, it's closed before your `__destruct` method is called. Even more, in [mysql_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) documentation it's said:

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

By the way, I usually think of `__destruct` as of internal method (and quite rarely find use for it): PHP is not C++, the whole concept of freeing resources is rather different here (by a plenty of reasons). If I need to perform some cleanup task, I usually use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), as it turned out to be way more predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a home grown `mysql` wrapper, I would use `PDO`.

Failing that, PHP closes non-persistent DB connections on its own.  It's possible that it does this before it calls object destructors obviating the need for that method.

Comment: The "classic" MySQL PHP API is perfectly acceptable.  raina77ow has identified the actual problem ... and the solution ... below.

Comment: @paulsm4 he said the exact same reason that I did: apparently `__destruct` is called after the gc closes the connection (apparently freeing the resource).  As for the "classic" API being acceptable, not even the PHP documentation agrees with you: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php "Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."  Why create an *additional* wrapper for `mysql_*` when there are superior ones already out there?